# How to pull in commonly used DataObjects/Templates when using composer to install a fresh copy of Silverstripe?

Tags: composer-php, silverstripe

I have my composer.json file that I use to start all new projects with like so:

**composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "silverstripe/installer",
    "description": "The SilverStripe Framework Installer",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "silverstripe/cms": "3.2.0",
        "silverstripe/framework": "3.2.0",
        "silverstripe/reports": "3.2.0",
        "silverstripe/siteconfig": "3.2.0",
        "silverstripe-themes/simple": "3.1.*",
        "silverstripe-australia/gridfieldextensions": "*",
        "colymba/gridfield-bulk-editing-tools": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/PHPUnit": "~3.7"
    },
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 600
    },
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

If I want to pull in some commonly used `dataobjects` and or `template` `.ss` files how would I go about doing this?

E.g for example's sake if I had a `SlideShow.php` `Dataobject` that I want to pull in with every project - The directory structure looks like this `TestFolder->mysite->code->dataobjects->Slideshow.php` - How can I pull this file in and make it so it goes into the correct directory when I have pulled in a fresh copy of Silverstripe using composer.

**Slideshow.php**

```
<?php

class Slideshow extends DataObject {

    private static $db = array(
        'Title' => 'Varchar(255)',
        'ButtonTitleText' => 'Varchar(255)',
    );

    private static $has_one = array(
        'Image' => 'Image',
    );

    private static $summary_fields = array(
        'Image.Thumbnail' => 'Thumbnail',
        'Title' => 'Title'
    );
}
```

Comment: composer is for installing modules. You could make your own modules (either official or private repos just for yourself) and install them using composer. Or you make a "boilerplate" repository for yourself with your favourite files and clone this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not create your slideshow as a module, which is fairly simple to be honest.. it's just putting the files in a new folder structure. Once you do that you can configure composer to pull your new module in to the site on initial setup.